# Magento index table does not has some checkbox

Tags: magento

I have magento enterprise edition 1.13. After installation in admin panel on Index Management page I have the next picture:[image]

I have tried run cron.php and shell/indexer.php already.
Can someone tell me why some checkboxes are absent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this issue. The indexes with checkboxes next to their names must be managed manually of course. The other indexes **update automatically according to the schedule set in your Magento cron job**.
Magento Enterprise also has some options with indexes. You can find it System > Configuration > Index Management. More about this issue you can find [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing#overview-how-11300#overview-index-mgmt) (dead link)

Closest doc about index management : [here](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee/user_guide/system-operations/index-management.html)